# How to sort in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Looked online to get a better understanding of both Xcode and Swift and I've tried some things out and get errors. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1. I've tried using `sort`, but I'm for the version of swift I have it's `sorted(by:)` and I haven't gotten it to work so far. If you can please explain what I need to do and maybe leave an example that would be much appreciated!

There are 4 tasks I'm supposed to do.

1. Assign a list of unique random numbers to 5 variables and 5 constants. (Not sure if the way I did it was right or if I should use
   `Int(arc4random_uniform(50))`.
2. Place them in an array
3. Sort by ascending order
4. Store them in a dictionary using key values to retrieve the highest and lowest number easily.

I'll leave my code here.

[image: code snippet]

Comment: What do you think the error message "Expected ]" might mean? How many "[" do you have? How many "]" do you have?

Comment: All I know for certain is that there is a little arrow under the = sign. When I write [Int] as [Int]] I then get a different error saying that '[String : [Int]]' cannot be used with array literal.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't post a picture of code. Copy/paste your actual code into your answer and use the code tagging tool to mark it as code. (If you select a block of text and tap the "{}" button, it indents the block of code by 4 spaces, causing the markup display to put it in a code block.)

Comment: Regarding your last point, what does a dictionary have to do with that. When you have your array sorted, you can use `first` and `last` methods to quickly get those values. What does a dictionary have to do with it?

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment to me. Steps 1 and 4 seem silly, arbitrary, and pointless. It would be much cleaner and simpler to populate an array with 5 random numbers directly rather than storing values into separate variables.

Comment: `'[String : [Int]]' cannot be used with array literal.` because you are assigning an array to the variable and not a dictionary of type `[String : [Int]]` which would look more like `["arrayofvariables":[1,2,3]]`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should probably use arc4random_uniform to generate your random numbers.

If you must store your results into a dictionary (this is silly, as Rob points out in his comment) I would suggest using a dictionary of type `[Int:Int]`. That way you can use the array indexes as the keys.

Thus your dictionary declaration would be something like this:

```
var resultsDict: [Int:Int] = [:]
```

You could populate your dictionary using

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerated {
  resultsDict[index] = value
}
```

Then you could fetch the first result using

```
resultsDict[0]
```

And fetch the last result using

```
resultsDict[resultsDict.count - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

from use case it makes no sense place them in variables and constants

my solution would be:

```
// 1. Assign a list of unique random numbers to 5 variables and 5 constants. why variables and constants?
// 2. Place them in an array
var arr = (1...10).map{ _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(50)) }
print(arr) // -> [19, 41, 27, 47, 12, 38, 38, 48, 5, 41]

// 3. Sort by ascending order 
arr.sort()
print(arr) // -> [5, 12, 19, 27, 38, 38, 41, 41, 47, 48]

// 4. to retrieve the highest and lowest number easily
print(arr.first!) // -> 5
print(arr.last!)  // -> 48
```

or in short:

```
var arr2 = (1...10).map{ _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(50)) }.sorted()

print(arr2)        // -> [4, 5, 14, 20, 21, 27, 30, 37, 39, 43]
print(arr2.first!) // -> 4
print(arr2.last!)  // -> 43
```